# How do I setup a "build" script for a custom (vanilla Javascript) Ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm a tech teacher and I'm designing a coding course for high school students.  I want to teach them Ionic without also having to teach them React, Angular, or Vue.  They already know basic web development, so I want them to be able to create iOS, Android, and web apps using only vanilla Javascript + Ionic.

When I run "ionic init" to get started, I'm forced to select from Angluar, React, Vue, or Custom.  So, of course, I select Custom.

Then I start building a "Hello World" app.  When it comes time to view the simple app in Android Studio, I run "ionic capacitor add android" and then "npx cap open android."  All good.

The problem arises when I start adding more to my simple app, and then try to view those changes in Android Studio. Normally, this would be done by running "ionic capacitor copy android".  But that doesn't work in my custom app.  I get this error message:

```
[ERROR] Cannot perform build.

Since you're using the custom project type, you must provide the ionic:build npm script so the Ionic CLI can build your project.
```

How do I solve this problem?  **How I provide a build script for my custom app?**

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I got same issue, all because I selected custom type.  Actually, I really not needed to use vue, angular or react in my project, I just using html and js only.  Is there a ionic:build and ionic:serve script to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using vanilaJS you shouldn't need any build step at all. Just put your `index.html` to `www` folder, with some content. You can start off with something like

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Ionic without any framework</title>

    <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core@latest/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core@latest/css/ionic.bundle.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<!-- We create a vanilla Javascript function to call the alert -->
<script>
    hello = async function () {
        alert('Hello World!');
    };
</script>

<!-- We declare an Ionic app using the <ion-app/> element -->
<ion-app>
    <!-- Cool thing, the Ionic CSS utilities could be used too -->
    <ion-content text-center>
        <h1>Basic usage</h1>
        <!-- We add an ion-button with an onclick event -->
        <ion-button onclick="hello()">Click me</ion-button>
    </ion-content>
</ion-app>

</body>
</html>
```

and then `ionic capacitor copy android` should work. (I assume following initialization steps `ionic init`, `npm init`, `ionic capacitor add android`)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer.  Unfortunately, I've already done everything that you said. "ionic capacitor add android" works fine.  But "ionic capacitor copy android" specifically throws an error stating "you must provide the ionic:build npm script so the Ionic CLI can build your project."

Comment: Right now, the best I can do is delete the android folder every time I need to view changes in Android Studio.  After deleting the folder, not only do I need to re-run "ionic capacitor add android", but I also need to reopen the android folder in Android Studio, which is a major hassle.

Comment: The "ionic serve"command—which allows me to view the app in a web browser—gives a similar error.  It says: "you must provide the ionic:serve npm script so the Ionic CLI can serve your project."  Fortunately, I've found a workaround for that problem—I simply use Visual Studio Code's "Live Server" extension to serve the app locally.

Comment: what version of `ionic cli` do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I think what is needed after making any changes is to run `npx cap sync` and then `npx cap open android`.